# Microsoft Sync Framework mirror sync for file system

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

I am looking to use Microsoft Sync Framework to sync file system directories. I am interested in a "mirror sync" which ensures that the target directory looks exactly like the source directory. That means that if a file is deleted on the source, it will be deleted on the target as well. Similarly, if for some reason target file is newer, source file should still overwrite it. Basically after the sync is done, target will look exactly like the source no matter what. I noticed that the `SyncOrchestrator` has a `Direction` property which I've set to `SyncDirectionOrder.Upload` but the above two scenarios are still not handled the way I'd like (i.e. newer file is preserved, and target file is not deleted). Is there is anything I can do to make the sync work the way I want? Handle some event or override a certain behaviour?

Comment: i am facing the same question, can you please tell me what solution did you choose?

Answer (score 0):

Sync Fx does incremental syncs, meaning, it will only try sync files that has change in source. If it hasn't change, its not detected.

If you simply want the folders to be identical, why not simply do plain copy overwriting the destination rather than using Sync Fx?

if you really want to do it, delete the sync metadata file and sync fx has no idea what has been synched, therefore it's going to apply the files from the source to the destination.

Comment: I think plain overwriting everything is grossly inefficient especially when file sets are hundreds of GB in size. I can definitely write my own classes that do the work but was hoping to use something already built.

Comment: unfortunately, sync fx doesnt go comparing what has changed on both source and destination. when you sync, it will changes made since the last sync from the source and send it to the destination. it doesnt go comparing files from the source to the files on the destination. if you still want to use Sync Fx, you can have the upload work as it is and have it overwrite destination when conflicts are detected. Then you can do DetectChanges on the destination to detect files deleted that you want to restore from source. but you have to do the copying from source outside of Sync Fx.