# Mirror file sync over network

Tags: c#, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

We consider MS Sync Framework to use for deployment solutions and updates to several (50+) servers (file shares with auth). We want one-to-many one-way mirror-style file sync.

What we need:

- Source file changed - Destination file overwriten
- Source file deleted - Destination file deleted
- Source file added - Destination file added
- Destination file changed - Destination file overwriten by Source
- Destination file deleted - Destination file added from Source
- Destination file added - Destination file deleted if no such file at Source

Only whats need to maintain integrity should be uploaded to destination.

*Optional: Everything should be done using tmp folder at destination (upload to tmp folder, then replace main folder).*

Is it possible to create one-to-many one-way mirror-style file sync using Microsoft Sync Framework?

As far as I found MS Sync Framework can not compare metadata of source and destination, so it can't do what I want, right? May be there could another solution/framework/or smth to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

not sure how you came into conclusion that Sync Fx cannot compare metadata because that's how it actually works, by metadata (not by contents of the file)

you're scenario should be possible. you should create separate metadata file for each sync pair.

Comment: I think i found your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280858/microsoft-sync-framework-mirror-sync-for-file-system where you say that Sync Fx does not compare metadata, it only makes incremental syncs